# How to call Spring Data repository method from service/controller with specific projection name?

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I can call repo method directly with `?projection=` parameter (`/api/records/search/findByName?projection=light&...`). I'm searching a way to call the same method from controller/service passing projection name ? Is some parameter in repo method similar to `Pageable` for projections ?

Simple repo method like below:

```
public interface RecordRepository extends JpaRepository<Record, Long> {
    Page<Record> findByName(@Param("name") String name, Pageable pageable);
}

@Projection(name = "light", types = {Record.class})
public interface RecordProjection {
   // ...
}
```

I can do it when define method in repo like below, but would like to have more universal method and call it from service with other projections for example. Anybody help ?

```
Page<RecordProjection> findByName(@Param("name") String name, Pageable pageable);
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using dynamic projections as described [here (section 5)](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-projections)?

Your repo will look something like this

```
Page<T> findByName(@Param("name") String name, Pageable pageable, Class<T> projectionClass);
```

And in your controller i expect something like

```
return repository.findByName(nameParameter,page,getProjectionClass(projectionNameParameter));
```

just implement your `getProjectionClass(projectionNameParameter)` and you are good to go